# Result set is multiplied after each query made

Tags: mysql, node.js, innodb

Each select query return the result set but with all the previous results, thus the result buffer is growing after each query:

If I run the next query:

```
conn.query('SELECT * FROM table_name;', function(err, result){
    if(!err){
        callback(result);
    }
    else{
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

And then I run it again, result will hold all the table content, twice and goes on.

I have tried all kind of things such as:

SQL_NO_CACHE after the SELECT statement

but nothing solves my problem.

How can i avoid it?